# Excel VBA User Defined Function | Does not work on specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

After several days working on my first User Defined Function ("UDF"), I finally got one working as expected. My function has the purpose of simplifying an "Index+Match+Offset" excel function.

For example, that is its code :

```
Public Function DADOSMACRO(Data_I_want As String, Date_I_want As Date) As Double
Application.Volatile

Dim year As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim column As Integer

Year = Year(Data_Procurada)
Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Data_I_want, Range("Macro").Columns(2), 0)
Column = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Year, Range("Macro!6:6").Rows(1), 0)


DADOSMACRO = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Macro"), row, column)


End Function
```

The question is, my function works perfectly on several worksheets on my worktable, but I don´t know why, there is a worksheet that every time it´s recalculated, it "broke" my UDF.

So, if I go to any other worksheet and press F9, my numbers are there, if I go to that specific table and press F9, my whole workbook is "broke"

Comment: Your function needs some way to know which sheet it's to look at for the Match operations - you don't specify a sheet so the `Range()` calls default to the ActiveSheet.  That's why it breaks when you recalculate with a different sheet active.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The "Macro" set on the Range() is a named range on excel. My UDF works on other 7 sheets, but the newer sheet was the only that does not work.

Comment: Thinking about what you sad, I could figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Tim´s comment I went check my named ranges. My workbook used to have only one named range, the range "macro".

The error was somehow related to new named ranges that my excel imported from another workbook that I was using at same time and copying formulas.

For some reason, the old sheets were working anyway because such sheets were created **before** the new named ranges to appear.

The new sheet was created after the importing of the others named ranges, so, it did not work.

As soon as I cleaned the named ranges, the UDF started to work on all sheets.

Regards,